# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$password in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using hashing algorithm using Laravel Hashing.

**But got this error**

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$password

**Here is my function**

```
public function signin(LoginFormValidation $request)
{
    $user_password = $request->password;

    $data = User::where('email','=',$request->email); 

    if (Hash::check($user_password, $data->password, flase))
    {
        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "still not";
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not `flase` it is `false`, and you should use `first()` or `get()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$data = User::where('email','=',$request->email);
```

To

```
$data = User::where('email','=',$request->email)->first();
```

And change:

```
if (Hash::check($user_password, $data->password, flase))
```

To

```
if (Hash::check($user_password, optional($data)->password))
```

Comment: @Sohel0415......it gives new error ` Trying to get property 'password' of non-object`

Comment: what version of laravel you are using?

Comment: It means there's no user with the given email in the database

Comment: @Sohel0415...new error shows `local.ERROR: Type error: Argument 3 passed to Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher::check() must be of the type array, boolean given`...

Comment: @Sohel0415...it still given `Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::$password `....How !!!

Comment: @Raff please show us what `dd($request->all())` gives

Comment: @Sohel0415....Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169300/discussion-between-raff-and-sohel0415).

Answer (score 0):

Make your code better, I have added a fix and an additional chek in your IF statement. This additional check is required for the case where `$data` does not obtain a valid result.

```
public function signin(LoginFormValidation $request)
{
    $user_password = $request->password;

    $data = User::where('email','=',$request->email)->first(); 

    if ($data && Hash::check($user_password, $data->password))
    {
        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "still not";
    }
}
```

Comment: .....error changed and gives new error `Type error: Argument 3 passed to Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher::check() must be of the type array, boolean given`

Comment: you can skip passing a 3rd parameter, why do you need it? I will modify my answer as per your requirements

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function signin(Request $request)  //chnaged object to Request
{
    $user_password = $request->password;

    $data = User::where('email',$request->email)->first();  // Added first()

    if ($data  && Hash::check($user_password, $data->password, false)) // typo error false
    {
        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "still not";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I see your model `User` ?
I think you should remove `password` from `protected $hidden` properties then try again.
Let me know if you make it